# Vnstat and sadc eating 100% CPU

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, internet, cpu-usage

I am using *Linux Mint 18* with *xfce4*. It happens sometimes that `vnstat` and `sadc` eat 100% CPU and nothing works, I have to shutdown the system forcefully.And also if I open terminal and execute `kill` command I get no response from terminal.

[image]

and the weird thing is this that my LAN stops working.And it is confirmed that each time I found only these two processes eating all CPU.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think it runs all the time, daemon. And what else info can I provide?

Comment: Sorry, was mistaking vnstat for something else. This can be a larger symptom of other problems, you need to describe what the server does and collect logs and maybe performance data. We cannot guess what is happening with so little troubleshooting data.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it is desktop pc for personal use.

Comment: If I had to guess, lack of disk space, RAM, web browser with too many tabs, or a couple of those together.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I agree with browser with many tabs.Should I disable this daemon?

Comment: If it is a station just for personal use, disable both. Be aware they might just be a symptom and not the cause.